# How to disable endpoint identification for java 1.8.181 version

Tags: java, java-8, ldap

When I upgraded java from 1.8.161 to 1.8.181,  I am not able to connect to LDAP from my application, 
i get below exception when i try to login to application with a user that is active in LDAP.

> javax.naming.CommunicationException: : [Root exception is
>    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
>   No subject alternative names matching IP address  found]

I found the below [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html) on the Oracle site for version 1.8.181

> **Changes**
>
> core-libs/javax.naming
>   ➜ Improve LDAP support
>   Endpoint identification has been enabled on LDAPS connections.
>
> To improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS ) connections, endpoint identification 
>   algorithms have been enabled by default.
>
> Note that there may be situations where some applications that were previously able to successfully connect 
>   to an LDAPS server may no longer be able to do so. 
>   Such applications may, if they deem appropriate, disable endpoint identification using a 
>   new system property: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification`.
>
> Define this system property (or set it to true) to disable endpoint identification algorithms.

---

I tried to set the property to true as below along with other properties. But still it throws same error.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ctxFactory);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, secPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, secAuthentication);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, secCredentials);
   env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification" ,disableEndpointIdentification);
    DirContext ldapCtx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Need your help how and where exactly we need to set the property 
`com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification` to true.

There is no such constant String variable related to this in Context Interface too.

If I revert back to java 1.8.161  version it works fine.

Comment: maybe you can try `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true` in java start command line? Because doc tells about application system property and not about Ldap context environment...

Comment: Wonderful Vadim!!. Thanks a lot for reminding about the small point that i missed.Yes I added in Eclipse VM argurments and as well as in JBOSS Server standalone.bat file ====>set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%  -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true"

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 22):

doc tells about application system property and not about Ldap context environment

then it needs to be setup on application JVM (java command line) for the app as

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true
```

Comment: The sad part is the only information I can find tell you how to disable it but, not how to get it working with it enabled.

Comment: my error message saying "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ldaps.xx.com found." So it took a while to pin down the issue.

Comment: hi, I tried this (even verified the env variable inside the code) but it doesn't alleviate the problem. I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590737/during-an-ssl-soap-request-sslhandshake-consume-ignores-value-of-com-sun-jndi-l and was wondering if you could please take a look? :)

Answer (score 1):

Add SAN for your IP Address to the certificate configured on your LDAP

e.g. for your certificate request config (request.inf)

```
[RequestAttributes]
SAN="ipaddress=10.233.207.65"

[Extensions] 
2.5.29.17 = "{text}" 
continue_ = "ipaddress=10.233.207.65"
```

and for the certificate generation something like

```
keyUsage=digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
subjectAltName=@alt_names

[alt_names]
IP = 10.233.207.65
```

in the extfile configuration