# Modifying a Java property at OS/Host System Level

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Earlier our install of cluster worked as expected. However after the recent Linux patch, it stopped working. We notice that JDK minor version/security base line has changed to 1.8.0_181-b13. Finding the corresponding [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html) : . 
It reads :

> Changes core-libs/javax.naming ➜ Improve LDAP support Endpoint
>   identification has been enabled on LDAPS connections.
>
> To improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS )
>   connections, endpoint identification algorithms have been enabled by
>   default.
>
> Note that there may be situations where some applications that were
>   previously able to successfully connect to an LDAPS server may no
>   longer be able to do so. Such applications may, if they deem
>   appropriate, disable endpoint identification using a new system
>   property: com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification.
>
> Define this system property (or set it to true) to disable endpoint
>   identification algorithms.
>
> JDK-8200666 (not public)

For our cluster boot strap script I added JAVA_OPTS to include com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true and it worked fine.

However our cluster software has multiple application components which talk to Active Directory for authentication and we will need to add this property at least in 7/8 more places and restart them.

**Instead is a there a way to add/modify a property at OS/System/JDK level so that we do not need to modify the start script for all the other application components?**

Any help in this direction will be helpful.

Regards,
-JE

Comment: Similar issue I saw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449801/how-to-disable-endpoint-identification-for-java-1-8-181-version, I did same thing at application level. Now, looking a way to set this at System/OS level. Thanks.

Comment: There's no standard way of doing this beyond what you're doing - adding it to an environment variable (`JAVA_OPTS` being the standard name.) If you want, you can just modify the build scripts to use a different environment variable and use that instead (if you don't want to intefere with `JAVA_OPTS` considering that's likely used elsewhere..)

Comment: Thanks @michael-berry Well, if thats the resort, I would update all the startup scripts with additional JAVA_OPTS. I think the issue is, every time we do patch or upgrade the component, it's JAVA_OPTs will need to be changed, as we cannot set this at JDK level.